# Issue when writing to HDFS using spring data hadoop

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data, spring-data-hadoop

I was trying to write a simple text to HDFS using spring data hadoop.
But I'm getting an unknown issue upon writing.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.StoreException: Store output
>   context not yet initialized; nested exception is java.io.IOException:
>   Unexpected HTTP response: code=404 != 200, op=GETFILESTATUS,
>   message=Not Found     at
>   org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.getOutputContext(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.output.AbstractDataStreamWriter.getOutput(AbstractDataStreamWriter.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.output.TextFileWriter.write(TextFileWriter.java:132)
>     at com.mstack.app.MainApp.someMethod(MainApp.java:37)   at
>   com.mstack.app.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:32) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Unexpected HTTP response: code=404 != 200,
>   op=GETFILESTATUS, message=Not Found   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.validateResponse(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:347)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.access$200(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:613)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:492)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:488)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getHdfsFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:848)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:858)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)     at
>   org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.findInitFiles(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.initOutputContext(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.getOutputContext(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:133)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Content-Type "text/plain"
>   is incompatible with "application/json" (parsed="text/plain")     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.jsonParse(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:320)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.validateResponse(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:343)
>     ... 18 more

**My application-context.xml :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">


    <hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfigBean">
        fs.defaultFS=${hdp.fs}
    </hdp:configuration>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <beans:bean id="textFileWriter"
        class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.output.TextFileWriter">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="hadoopConfigBean"></beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1"
            type="org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path" value="/user/mhduser"></beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" type="org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.codec.CodecInfo" >
        <beans:null></beans:null>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="hadoop-configs.properties" />
</beans:beans>
```

Main class :-

```
public class MainApp {

    @Autowired
    TextFileWriter textFileWriter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/application-context.xml",
                MainApp.class);
        System.out.println("Context loaded...");
        MainApp obj = new MainApp();
        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(obj);
        obj.someMethod();
    }

    private void someMethod() {
        try {
            textFileWriter.write("Something");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: The file was not found on the server?

Comment: Not sure how well webhdfs works but what is your `hdp.fs` setting?

Comment: @JanneValkealahti : My hdp.fs setting -hdp.fs=webhdfs://192.168.1.53:8020

Comment: Port `8020` is used for `hdfs` protocol, you need namenode's http port which is `50075` or whatever else it's set to use.

Comment: Thought with that port you should use `hdfs://192.168.1.53:8020` and not `webhdfs`.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example to write a sample  text data to the HDFS via spring data hdp ? I checked the reference doc but no samples were found. Or please provide it as the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some samples here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples. Thought nothing store specific so I created a simple gist based on Spring Boot which can be run via its CLI. https://gist.github.com/jvalkeal/8145f0618f25c1d25d19f4e1e89de1e6

Also worth to look what we do in unit tests https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/tree/master/spring-hadoop-store/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/store

Comment: Thanks ! It was really helpful! :)